# How to make datetime fields neutral to timezone when using Javascript to set/get value

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In my project, there are several datetime typed fields , like a flight's departure/arrival date and time, which should be exactly the same whereever a user edit them.

I use ASP.NET MVC3 and dojo to build up the application. At back end, I can handle the given value as UTC time and save it to DB. But when it passed to front end using Json, Javascript seems to adjust it to local time and the date/time picker on page shows adjusted value. It seems when I use new Date(...), it automatically adjusts to local time.

Below is the parse function I use on page (because ASP.NET MVC3's JsonRest returns date like "/Date(464371200000)/").

```
function (/*string*/dateStr) {
        if (!dateStr) {
            return dateStr;
        }
        var jsonResultPattern = /Date\([+-]?(\d+)\)/;
        if (dateStr.match(jsonResultPattern)) {
            return new Date(parseInt(dateStr.substr(6)));
        }
        else {
            return dateStr;
        }
    },
```

How can I implement for this case? Is there a best practice or example?

Answer (score 1):

Change the return to the following for UTC time:

```
return new Date(parseInt(dateStr.substr(6))).toUTCString();
```

All dates in javascript are stored internally as UTC. If you want the function to return the actual date object and you're using certain methods such as `getFullYear()` in your widget, it converts it to local time. If you want to keep it in UTC, you have to use the UTC methods, such as:

```
dateObj.getUTCFullYear();          // Year as a 4-Digit Number
dateObj.getUTCMonth();             // Month as a number from 0 - 11
dateObj.getUTCDate();              // Day of the Month as a number from 1 - 31
dateObj.getUTCDay();               // Day of the Week as a number from 0 - 6
dateObj.getUTCHours();             // Hours as a number from 0 - 23
dateObj.getUTCMinutes();           // Minutes as a number from 0 - 59
dateObj.getUTCSeconds();           // Seconds as a number from 0 - 59
dateObj.getUTCMilliseconds();      // Milliseconds as a number from 0 - 999
dateObj.toUTCString();             // The entire Date as a string in UTC
```

If you wish to set the object, use the same methods as above but change the word get to set (e.g. - `dateObj.setUTCFullYear(1984);`).

Comment: But I need the Date object to pass to widget.

Comment: I changed the answer to have a bit more information. I'm not quite sure what it is you're trying to do exactly, since you've only presented the parse function but are having problems with some widget. Either way, I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Steve. I tried your way and it works fine after some simple tests. I need more time to test because it's really a big modification.